# Converting from 'H:mm a' format back to DateTime can't be parsed

Tags: date, luxon

```
const date = DateTime.fromISO('2022-03-27T08:50').toFormat('H:mm a') // 08:50 AM

console.log(DateTime.fromISO(date))
```

If I attempt the above, in the console log I get this explanation in the 'invalid' field:

explanation: "the input "8:30 AM" can't be parsed as ISO 8601"
reason: "unparsable"

Is it not possible to revert the string back to a date?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse back "`8:30 AM`" as DateTime using [`fromFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat):

> Create a DateTime from an input string and format string. Defaults to en-US if no locale has been specified, regardless of the system's locale. For a table of tokens and their interpretations, see [here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing?id=table-of-tokens).

but the information about year, month and day are lost and so the new DateTime will default to the current day.

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const date = DateTime.fromISO('2022-03-27T08:50').toFormat('H:mm a') // 8:50 AM

console.log(DateTime.fromFormat(date, 'h:mm a').toISO())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```